# Php output error

Tags: php

What is wrong with my code?

```
$text="hello world";
echo "the string above contains .$text";?>
```

**I am getting an error message when the code is executed, thanks!**

Comment: WHAT error message? In 99,99% of cases, error message is stupidly obvious to tell what is wrong.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: [Nothing wrong with that code](https://eval.in/239391).

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write this ? `echo "the string above contains " . $text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntex error on line 2,
**try this way**

```
<?php
$text="hello world";
echo "the string above contains $text";?>
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you forgot to write the php starting tag

```html
<?php
 $text="hello world";
 echo "the string above contains .$text";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "hello world";
echo "text is " . $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have omitted this first line:

```
<?php 
$text="hello world";
echo "the string above contains ".$text;
?>
```